# SQL Finding information about Person in two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rows

I have to following Database called Data1

```
DateOfBooking | Short   |  Long  |  TimeOfBooking  | ID
-------------------------------------------------------
14.06.2016    | KAL     |  blabla| 13:02           | 1
14.06.2016    | DEF     |  del   | 14:02           | 3
14.06.2016    | KAL     |  blabla| 17:34           | 2
14.06.2016    | DOL     |  blub  | 13:02           | 1
```

I want to to find the ID of the person were KAL at 13:02 and DOL at 13:02 where booked but only if both were booked (at the same time).

KAL and DOL are always booked at the same TimeOfBooking for one ID but I can't figure out how to get the result.
I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT Data1.ID
FROM Data1
WHERE (((Data1.Short = 'KAL') AND (Data1.Long Like 'blabla')) 
AND ((((Data1.Short = 'DOL') AND (Data1.Long Like 'blub')))
Group BY Data1.ID
```

Of course this did not work as it only looks into one row. Is there a way to look into both rows and find the corresponding ID?

Thank you.

Comment: No need for both SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY here, both of them are removing duplicates.

Comment: good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but this will return the data when a KOL and a DOL have same id and timestamp:

```
select tk.*, td.*
from (select * from data1 where Short = 'KAL') tk
join (select * from data1 where Short = 'DOL') td
  ON tk.id = td.id and tk.TimeOfBooking = td.TimeOfBooking
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally worked. That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation, by the id and booking time -- and then checking for the two `short` values:

```
select d.id
from data1 d
where d.short in ('KAL', 'DOL')
group by d.id, d.timeofbooking
having count(distinct d.short) = 2;
```

If you want the full records, an alternative method uses `exists`, but is a bit more complicated:

```
select d.*
from data1 d
where (d.short = 'KAL' and
       exists (select 1 from data1 d2
               where d2.id = d.id and
                     d2.timeofbooking = d.timeofbooking and
                     d2.short = 'DOL'
              )
      ) or
      (d.short = 'DOL' and
       exists (select 1 from data1 d2
               where d2.id = d.id and
                     d2.timeofbooking = d.timeofbooking and
                     d2.short = 'KAL'
              )
      );
```

Or, even, using window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             min(short) over (partition by id, timeofbooking) as minshort,
             max(short) over (partition by id, timeofbooking) as maxshort
      from data1
      where short in ('KAL', 'DOL')
     ) d
where minshort <> maxshort;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your many solutions! The aggregation method works the fastest on my database so I will use that and read up on the aggregation methods :D